# Local JSON deserialization in Flutter using Json_Serializable

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to access a local JSON file in my flutter app but am stuck on how to:
1) Load the json file into my project
2) Parse/decode it using the serialization module I've put together.

The code for the serialisation module Classes:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'testJson.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class BaseResponse extends Object with _$BaseResponseSerializerMixin {

  final List<Topics> topic;

  BaseResponse(
      this.topic
      );

  factory BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BaseResponseFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Topics extends Object with _$TopicsSerializerMixin {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String color;
  final List<Reading> reading;
  final int tCompletion;


  Topics(
    this.id,
      this.name,
      this.color,
      this.reading,
      this.tCompletion

);

  factory Topics.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TopicsFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Reading extends Object with _$ReadingSerializerMixin{
  final String name;
  final int nLos;
  final String description;
  final String summary;
  final List<LOS> los;
  final int  rCompletion;

  Reading(
      this.name,
      this.nLos,
      this.description,
      this.summary,
      this.los,
      this.rCompletion,
      );

  factory Reading.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ReadingFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class LOS extends Object with _$LOSSerializerMixin{
  final int id;
  final String objective;
  final String description;
  final String formulae;

  LOS(this.id, this.objective, this.description, this.formulae);

  factory LOS.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LOSFromJson(json);
}


@JsonLiteral('jsondata.json')
Map get glossaryData => _$glossaryDataJsonLiteral;
```

I have built a Model to interpret the response for the Topic Class

```
class topicModel {

  final String topic;
  final String color;
  final int completion;


  topicModel({
    this.topic,
    this.color,
    this.completion

  });

  topicModel.fromResponse(Topics response)
  : topic = response.name,
    color = response.color,
    completion = response.tCompletion;

}
```

I'm trying to use future builder to load the local JSON file, but am struggling to return the data and parse it through the classes / model

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(context: context),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> jsonData) {
        if (!jsonData.hasData) {
        return Text('not loaded');
        }
        return Text('loaded'); 

        },


}
      Future<List<topicModel>> getData({BuildContext context}) async {
  String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data/jsondata.json");
  Map jsonMap = json.decode(data);

  var testdata = BaseResponse.fromJson(jsonMap);
  return topicModel.fromResponse(testdata) as List;

}
```